# Send Order Email to Mulitiple Emails

Tags: magento-1.8, module

Is anyone aware of a Magento module that allows you to input multiple emails on the order page or customer account? This would only need to be done from the admin side.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure magento to CC/BCC all emails to your mail address.

But I assume that you are talking about different mail addresses. And then the answer is no I don't know any extension which does this.

But rewriting `Mage_Sales_Model_Order` can easily achieve this, if you only want to write the email to different persons. If you want to store it too, it is more work.